# XML Document Wrapping

Tags: c#, .net

I’m having a requirement to create a XML Document and load the same with a string.
I’ve written a small test program to do the same.

```
string xmlString = "<Control1>" +
             "\n\t<Stamp type=\"This is \n\ta test\" />" +
             "\n</Control1>"
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml(xmlString);
Console.WriteLine(xmlDocument.InnerXml);
```

The string that I have used has multiple new line sequences "\n" (essentially used for wrapping).
But after doing the above mentioned steps, the new line sequence does not hold good for the Xml Document.
The output is I get is:

```
 <Control1><Stamp type="This is &#xA; a test" /></Control1>
```

But the output I need to get is:

```
 <Control1>
   <Stamp type="This is 
    a test" />
 </Control1>
```

Any pointers on how can I make sure that the formatting of the string is retained inside the XML Document as well.

Thanks in advance,
Kunal

Comment: Your example listings are invisible.

Comment: `XmlDocument` is obsolete. Have you tried `XDocument`, the new API that is intended to replace it?

Comment: @Timwi: `XmlDocument` IS NOT obsolete. `XDocument` is for LINQ to XML

Comment: @abatishchev i was getting ready to post that exact comment...

Comment: @abatishchev and @Nix: WTF? There is nothing about `XDocument` that requires the use of Linq. There is also nothing about `XmlDocument` that makes it somehow better for use without Linq.

Comment: @Timwi: Indeed there is. `System.Xml.Linq.XElement` and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx - example is about L2X

Comment: @abatishchev: My statement still stands. There is nothing about `XDocument` that requires the use of LINQ, and nor is there anything about `XmlDocument` that makes it somehow better for use without LINQ. You have not addressed either of this.

Answer (score 2):

By default it trims out white space.... set

```
  xmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace = true;
```

Read about [White Space in Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256097.aspx)

MSDN Documentation on XMLDocument [PreserveWhitespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.preservewhitespace.aspx) property